# How to create a query string using SQLiteOpenHelper class?

Tags: android, database, sqliteopenhelper

I want to create a table with an ID and an UNIQUE TEXT field such using:

```
@Override   
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{   
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_POSTS + "("
    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT," + KEY_URL + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL"+")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);  
}
```

But this isn't working.

```
07-23 10:35:53.937: E/AndroidRuntime(19078): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error: CREATE TABLE posts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,url TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL)
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

The Integer primary key in SQlite is AutoIncrement by default so remove the Auto Increment. Here  is the documentation [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)

Comment: Thank you, but if i use AUTOINCREMENT instead of AUTO_INCREMENT then it worked. I faced a new problem with Inserting values to database on Error inserting ... error code: 19 - Contraint failed. May be Only one primary and no UNIQUE another one column can exist in table?

Answer (score 0):

This will work to create the table, I tested it within my application and worked fine.

```
@Override   
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{   
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_POSTS + " ("
    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_URL + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL"+")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);  
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It OK and as Peshal told me that autoincrement is default.

Answer (score 0):

change AUTO_INCREMENT to autoincrement.

Comment: Thank you. But Error on inserting value: contraint failed. What is it can be?

Comment: I need more infomation.